# android TelephoneManager getting null in service

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have a service consist phone state listener and started by my application.in version 2.3.3

when I exit application Telephone Manager getting null therefore phone state listener does not work service code below  any idea?  where am I do wrong?

Service does not destroy when i exit application.but listener getting NULL. Telephone manager setting on setCallListener() method.

I have a service to be used initialize phonestatelistener. service is started with two ways:

1-by BOOT_COMPLETED receiver (works fine listener is not null and catch the calls) 2-by my application with startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyPhoneStateListener.class));

problem is that when the service is started by my application then my application finish in this case my listener does not work. i know that TelephoneManager=null value. How can i provide that make The service intent going on when application finish?

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends Service{

    SmsBroadcastReceiver _smsbroadcast;
    private Context context;

    MyCustomStateListener myCustomStateListener;
    TelephonyManager telephonymanager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        setCallListener();
        _smsbroadcast=new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
        GetShieldState();  


        return START_STICKY;

    }

    private void setCallListener()
    {

        try
        {
            if (telephonymanager==null)
            {               
                telephonymanager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                myCustomStateListener = new MyCustomStateListener(context,telephonymanager);
                telephonymanager.listen(myCustomStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        //Log.e("startservis","create");
        context=MyPhoneStateListener.this;      
        super.onCreate();    
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        Log.e("onDestroy","destroy");       
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) 
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unbind:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to give following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: i have it. i found the solution. i used System.exit(0) command that killed process and 2.3.3 version service stoped and recreated but not restart. so my listener was null. now i changed System.exit with finish. and i set listener also in create metod of service.